# Fingerprint scanner on Pc and Android Differences

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, android-mediascanner

I made plenty of research before asking this question. I want to develop an online payment android application which reads fingerprints from the organisation's database using my android phone. The organistion's database uses a usb PC fingerprint scanner to store its data.

1. Can phones with fingerprint scanner identify fingerprints from database stored with PC fingerprint scanner?

2.Did I really have to use Android M when developing a fingerprint applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please start by reading this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition.

Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs only allow to verify current user against user of device.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

If you want to match user on server (fingerprint data of users are stored on server) you have to use an AFIS solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_fingerprint_identification.

Here some providers of AFIS solution:

- http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
- http://au.nec.com/en_AU/solutions/security-and-public-safety/biometrics/afis-fingerprint-identification-features.html
- http://www.innovatrics.com/products
- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/afis/
- http://www.m2sys.com/automated-fingerprint-identification-system-afis/

Comment: @AasimYaz, is it useful ?

Comment: How to do the match between the phone fingerprint and the other stored in DB ...from android side what should i do ..thanks